# Is it possible to display tuples from database on the fly in android studio?

Tags: android, database, gridview

I'm working on an Android App where the user sends queries to a database and the tuples are displayed in a `Gridview`.

Below you can see the code of the function where the query is executed and the tuples are retrieved. The returned `ArrayList` is used in the Adapter of the `GridView` to be displayed.

```
public ArrayList<String> getTuples(String query){
    String z;
    String tmp;
    ArrayList<String> tuples= new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Connection con = this.CONN();
        if (con == null) {
            z = "Please check your internet connection";
        } else {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();               
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                tmp = rs.getString(1);
                tuples.add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        z = "Exceptions"+ex;
    }
    return tuples;
}
```

First all tuples must be retrieved, `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`, and then displayed.

**The problem is** that, because the tables consist of 300K - 800K tuples, some queries (e.g. the JOIN of two tables) take a lot of time.

Is there a way to display each tuple **ON THE FLY** (as soon as it arrives ) ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43650916/6142219

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview